# In which ways does Hilbert's Nullstellensatz fail if the field is not algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Hilbert's Nullstellensatz asserts, that if $k$ is  an algebraically closed fields, $I \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an ideal, then $I(V(I)) = \sqrt{I}$. So every polynomial that vanishes on the variety defined by $I$ is actually in the radical of $I$.

Obviously we always have the inclusion $\sqrt{I} \subset I(V(I))$.

Of course this is not true, if $k$ is not algebraically closed, the standard example is $f = x^2 +1  \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $V(f) = \emptyset$, i.e. $I(V(f)) = k[x]$.

My question is: Are there any other examples where the Nullstellensatz does not hold, but $I$ actually has zeroes? Or is this the only class of counterexamples?

Comment: What about $f = x(x^2+1)$ so $V(f) = \{ 0 \}$ and $I(V(f)) = \langle x \rangle$ while $\sqrt{\langle f \rangle} = \langle f \rangle$?